# SSIS project keeps failing with COM error

Tags: ssis, dts

On my SSIS project I keep getting a COM error when I open the project, and then everything runs incredibly slow.  The message says this:

> Uable to case COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.sqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper.IDTSObject100'  This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{...}' failed due to the following error:  The application called an interface that was marshalled for a different thread.  (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8001010E (RPC_E_WRONG_THRED))

I've no idea where to even begin trying to track down how to fix that. The solutions I've seen all say to register dts.dll but that dll doesn't seem to exist in my SQL Server installation.

Windows 2012 R2
VS 2017 Enterprise 15.7.3
   - SQL Server Integration Services designer - 14.0.3002.101
SQL Server 2016 Mgmt Studio - 13.0.16100.1
SQL Server 2016

Comment: I would try reinstalling/repairing your SSDT installation.

Comment: The reinstall is running now.  Thanks.  I'll report back when it's complete.

Comment: If the reinstall does not help, take a look at the last response in the following link regarding the same message with SSIS 2014.  https://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1647600-2799-1.aspx

Comment: Didn't help unfortunately :(  It is telling me that `Microsoft Integration services Projects 1.5 caused 56 seconds of unresponsiveness`.  None of the items in my .dtsx file have any yellow.  When a full run completes everything ends up with a green checkmark.

Comment: Does this problem only occurs on this one project? Or do other projects have the same issue?

Comment: This is the only project I have.  One of the remote tables takes like 3 minutes to query.  I think that's causing an issue here.